# Can the escape key be less evil on IE, please?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, internet-explorer

When I press the escape key while using IE, it erases the post I was about to submit. This is evil for the following reasons:

1. It is very close to the back-tick used for in-lining code.
2. As a vim user, it is a habit to press escape.
3. There just shouldn't be an easy way to accidentally erase my post.

Now, I do recognize that this is entirely my fault for using IE in the first place. But I think it would be good to make things nicer for those users whose company makes them use IE for whatever reason.

Comment: Is it standard behavior for Esc to clear text boxes in IE? I don't remember having noticed that before, although it's been quite some time since I used IE.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, that's standard behavior in IE. I just tried it on a couple different sites.

Comment: Esc Key is in use since ancient times of Mainframe. Although, I understand that initially it could be a pain but my suggestion is to take this as a learning curve.

Comment: That is a nasty surprise. The good news, though, is that you can just Ctrl-Z to undo that action and get your post back.

Comment: This is by design, anything related to IE is ephemeral including its use. It is unfortunate that your current sweat shop is forcing you to use such a tool, have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/jobs ? :)

Comment: Apple removed the ESC key in their latest MacBook Pro.

Comment: Wait. There are actually people who use *both* vim and IE? That's like somebody who plays American Football and classical ballet.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> This is evil

That's a complaint you should be directing to Microsoft<sup>1</sup>, since this behavior is [standard in Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535249.aspx) and not engineered by Stack Overflow. I trust that the developers have better things to do than deliberately destroy the user experience for users who have to browse the site with IE.

> But I think it would be good to make things nicer for those users whose company makes them use IE for whatever reason.

Why is it Stack Overflow's responsibility to warn users about this? No other site has seen the necessity, so why Stack Overflow? In fact, given that this is the first time in nearly a decade that anyone has complained about it since the Stack Overflow public beta, I'm not sure this is even a significant problem, as much as it sucks to happen to anyone.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Even if you do, this behavior is unlikely ever going to change, for obvious reasons.</sub>

Comment: _obvious reasons._ one of them is IE is like deprecated.

Comment: @Sagar V: Auditioning for Captain Obvious, I see.

Comment: Does that imply that Edge does *not* have this behavior, @Sagar?

Comment: @CodyGray I won't use that too. only Chrome. :)

Comment: @Cody Gray: Yes; this behavior is not present in any version of Microsoft Edge.